# Add second grouping to a grouped multi-panel barchart with a shared x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I tried to create a second grouping with a facet grid on top of an already existing plot:

[image]

But if I use facet_grid twice, the second one overrides the first facet_grid call.

[image]

Is there a way to get the be able to use the two facet_grids for a shared x-axis?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `facet_grid()`, these are the arguments (see the documentation):

```
facet_grid(
  rows = NULL,
  cols = NULL,
  scales = "fixed",
  space = "fixed",
  shrink = TRUE,
  labeller = "label_value",
  as.table = TRUE,
  switch = NULL,
  drop = TRUE,
  margins = FALSE,
  facets = NULL
)
```

Note that have both the argument `cols` and the argument `rows`. You can use both at the same time; `facet_wrap(rows = vars(first), rows = vars(second))+[...]`